# Evaluate the complex integral $\oint\frac{4i(z^2+4)}{z(z^2-16)}\sin\Big(\frac{5\pi}{z^2+4}\Big)dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I have to evaluate the following contour integral, along the positively oriented contour $C:|z-3|=2$

$$\oint\frac{4i(z^2+4)}{z(z^2-16)}\sin{\Bigg(\frac{5\pi}{z^2+4}\Bigg)}dz$$

Attempt:

since $z(z^2-16)=0$ is true if and only if $z=0$ or $z=\pm4$ but we can ignore everything but $4$ since it's the only one that's inside the contour.

so 
$$\oint\frac{\frac{4i(z^2+4)}{z(z+4)}\cdot\sin{\Big(\frac{5\pi}{z^2+4}\Big)}dz{}}{(z-4)}$$

By Cauchy  Integral formula.

$$f(\zeta)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{z-\zeta}dz$$

where $\gamma$ is a closed oriented curve.

$$f(z)=\frac{4i(z^2+4)}{z(z+4)}\sin{\Bigg(\frac{5\pi}{z^2+4}\Bigg)}dz$$
$\zeta=4$ so

$$f(4)=\frac{4i\cdot20}{4\cdot8}\sin{\Bigg(\frac{5\pi}{20}\Bigg)}dz\Rightarrow f(4)=\frac{5i}{2}\sin{}\frac{\pi}{4}$$
Giving us the final answer as

$$I=2\pi if(4)=-\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}$$

I'm not sure if this is correct and I was also wondering if there's any other way to approach this?

Comment: I did not check all the computations, but it looks fine and I think that it is the best approach.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Got confused cause another friend of mine got $I=\frac{-12\pi}{\sqrt{2}}=6\sqrt{2}\pi$.

Comment: my bad. $-6\sqrt{2}$

Comment: The computation looks correct too.

Comment: @user8700908 I've checked it and there is only a small error near the end of your computations: there is a $\pi$ missing. That is, the answer is $-\frac{5\pi}{\sqrt2}$.